# Lots of ENOENT (no such file or directory) errors after setup:upgrade, slowing down the server to a crawl for several hours

Tags: magento2

For a while I've had the problem that my Magento 2 installation slows down to a crawl with constant 100% processor usage after running `setup:upgrade`. It starts off by taking about 10 minutes to even load the first page, and then gradually speeds up. Usually it goes back to normal after a couple of hours, but right now it's still stuck at about a minute per page after several days.

After checking the `strace` using `htop` to see what's going on I noticed that there is a near endless stream of `ENOENT` errors, after some time the errors will be less prevalent until some hours later they stop. (see images below)

I have had this occur on other projects I have been working on as well, on a lot of different versions of Magento 2 and a lot of different combinations of modules. The only thing that seems to be a common factor is that I was using the [Porto](https://themeforest.net/item/porto-ultimate-responsive-magento-theme/9725864) theme on all these projects, but that is one of the most popular Magento themes and I can't find anyone with similar issues.

After running `setup:upgrade` and accessing the website:
[image: after setup:upgrade]

After about half an hour:
[image: after about half an hour]

Comment: I am pretty sure that your server has some issue.Please fix it

Comment: try: Delete vendor, delete composer.lock.
do composer install, setup:upgrade

Comment: Still the same problem sadly @NikunjVadariya